# Wifi connection doesn't stay alive when asleep, with iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4

Knowing that iOS4 support wifi stay alive in asleep is really happy thing. However I got some different experience:
I've got 2 iPods, iPod 2nd gen & iPod 3rd gen. Both updated to iOS 4 beta. iPod 2g can stay wifi on in sleep while iPod 3g always disconnect wifi in sleep. I ping both of them while they're in sleep mode, only iPod 2g keeps reply echo.

Could any often a hint to show the point I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Test with adding this on your plist :

```
UIRequiresPersistentWiFi = YES
```

With this the wifi is alive during all the life of your app.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759802/keep-wifi-connection-active-even-ipad-is-going-into-sleep-mode-locked-in-ios-5/13841334#13841334

Comment: Does it work if iphone goes to sleep and when device is locked?