# Keeping wifi/3g alive for locked iphone

Tags: iphone

I'm having trouble keeping wifi from disconnecting after 30 mins in an iphone app that needs to function when locked by the user.

The app normally does not sleep, but if the user so chooses they may lock the display. I'm adding a new feature to the app that sends data out over the network at 1 second intervals. prior to this there has been no network requirement for the app, and it has functioned as desired (music, timer-based processes) while user-locked.

The answer seemed to be here:
[Wifi connection doesn't stay alive when asleep, with iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138923/wifi-connection-doesnt-stay-alive-when-asleep-with-ios4)

But adding UIRequiresPersistentWifi boolean to info.plist doesn't keep it from timing out the wifi (i'm testing on Touch, iOS4.02) after 30 mins, even while the app is busy sending data out over the connetion. Maybe this only applies if the display sleeps itself, rather than user locks?

Related, I think there is no way to "stir" the display at any interval?  User pressing the home button is sufficient to bring back the wifi; unlocking is not necessary.

Also, I've read on the interwebs that it was stated in a WWDC that UIRequiresPersistentWifi applies to keeping alive 3G as well. Can anyone verify?

thanks

Comment: Turns out that though the docs state that UIRequiresPersistentWiFi will keep the connection alive for an app, according to Apple dev forums it is not possible when the screen is locked. Blech.

Comment: My solution is, since the required feature is funtionally iPhone exclusive, to implement a switch to allow the proximity sensor to darken the display. This should save juice if the device is put away for long periods with the app running.

Answer (score 1):

Your app may be getting suspended by the OS after a long enough period of user inactivity.

Under iOS 4.x there are certain types of apps that aren't suspended when the display is locked (music player, VOIP, etc.)  Apps that register as a VOIP type app might be allowed to keep a persistant network connection over a longer period.  However Apple may require that an app actually provide some VOIP functionality in order to register for that type in any app submitted for review.

Comment: Adding an array named UIBackgroundModes to info.plist, with a member "voip" did not keep the wifi going. However I think it shouldn't have anyway. To clarify, my app is not in the background when the 30min timeout occurs. It is the active app, with the display locked by the user.

Comment: Also, the app is functioning normally when locked, except for the disappearing network. It also stores data using core data, and the data for the period after wifi sleeps is recorded properly. Audio aspects of the app execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some activity that you need to perform network activity? From iOS5 onwards, we have noted that even if we send network packets (heartbeat timers), then also iOS 5 blocks it after locking device.

It is to be noted that services which requires VoIP continue to receive calls, and notifications do come when your phone is on sleep mode or locked. This means that WiFi is not totally closed. I dont know how this happens.

As an alternative you can use data carrier of your network provider as an alternative to WiFi in case WiFi has gone down. With UIRequiresPersistentWiFi, you just inform iOS5 that you would require WiFi to run your application, nothing else signifies whether it keeps your screen ON or OFF. For keeping your phone from autolock you can however use disableTimer = YES flag, in lieu of your battery charge.

Comment: You says "It is to be noted that services which requires VoIP continue to receive calls."

I disagree with this statement. I tested the current skype app and it was not the case : call is not received when i lock the screen. Can I ask you which is the voip application you tried ?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I tried Skype only. Called the skype running on locked iPad (downloaded fresh installer) and it showed the ringing phone.